# Google Maps API JS - save location

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, location

This seems undoable, but here's my problem:
I'm creating a web-based custom map with the Google Maps API to be incorporated into my client's app via a webview. I want to be able to save an app user's parking location in the map and only make that visible to the proper user. I know how how to access the user's location (via navigator.geolocation) and how to deduce what type of device a user is using (navigator.userAgentData.platform), but is there a way to somehow store a user's location on the website and then return it back to that user (and only that user) when they open the app again?